# Is it possible to customize the iOS Visionkit VNDocumentCameraViewController

Tags: ios, swift, visionkit

I am trying to scan a picture by using the controller VNDocumentCameraViewController from VisionKit. Is it possible to customize the controller by for example hiding the scan scan button and the flash option on the top? I just want to start scanning and getting notified if an image is recognized, without any interaction from the user

Comment: Due to Apple documentation, the VisionKit is a [small framework that lets your app use the system's document scanner](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit). So, to achieve custom implementation, you'd better refer to [Vision framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) as such.

Comment: have you find solution @emanyal

Comment: any solution on this

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple's Documentation, `VNDocumentCameraViewController` is **not customizable**. I too have been using the same and tried to customise it but nothing changes much. So to achieve custom implementation, either use `vision` framework and make your own UI or you can checkout the [We-Scan](https://github.com/WeTransfer/WeScan/tree/master) Repository on `Github` which works exactly the same as `VNDocumentCameraViewController` and is **fully customisable**.